# How to view the dynamically loaded code of an assembly?

Tags: c#

My code is receiving an array of bytes to build an assembly through a WCF service.

Ultimately I create my assembly object with:

```
Byte[] bytesFromWCF = ... // here I receive the bytes via WCF.
Assembly myAsm = Assembly.Load( bytesFromWCF );
```

This array of bytes comes from a MSIL file which is hosted in a web server. I don't have  direct access to the file.
The methods of this MSIL file are decorated with the attribute DebuggerHidden().

My question is if is there some way to view, in runtime, the code which is dynamically loaded in myAsm ?

I mean the code of the methods. By Reflection I can access to the types, create instances, call to methods, etc, but I am interested in analyzing the source code.

Comment: Why don't you download the file and open it in a .NET Decompiler? For example dotPeek. There you can analyse the sourcecode of the assembly.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the file. The array of bytes is received after approving an authorization process which I have omitted in my code for clarity.

Comment: @cls71: you can simply emulate the authentication process using curl, wget,... Or simply store the array of bytes in the file...

Comment: Perfect. I have emulated the authentication process, downloaded the bytes and with a decompiler I have seen the source code. Thanks very much.

Comment: @cls71 would be nice if you could accept my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to analyse the source code of the assembly is to save the byte array to a file and load the downloaded file into a .NET Decompiler ([dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) etc.).

Saving the byte array to a file can be achieved by the IO Namespace:

```
byte[] bytesFromWCF = ... // here I receive the bytes via WCF.
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("mylib.dll", bytesFromWCF);
var myAsm = Assembly.Load( bytesFromWCF );
...
```